# How to read a line from each of several files in each iteration of a single loop?

Tags: bash

I need to read from multiple file in one loop. I have one file with X coords, one file with Y coords and one file with chars on those coords.

For now I use `paste` to put these files together, and then in a while loop use `cut` to separate them like this:

```
paste x-file y-file char-file | while -r line; do
    Y=$(echo "$line" | cut -d\  -f1)
    X=$(echo "$line" | cut -d\  -f2)
    CHAR=$(echo "$line" | cut -d\  -f3)
done
```

but the problem with this is that it's *really* slow (calling `cut` again and again).

How should I do this to have in each loop proper values in `$Y`, `$X` and `$CHAR` while speeding things up?

Comment: Something like `while read X Y CHAR`?

Comment: you are right man ^_^ thanks. If you want reputation for accepted answer, just copy your comment (don't see option to accept comment as answer..).

Comment: See [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41646525/6862601).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash)

Comment: @codeforester, I don't see that as an adequate duplicate -- this question covers iterating over multiple files in lockstop. The OP isn't very clear about that, because they're *assuming* `paste` as a preprocessing step, but just clarifying that (making the `paste` explicit) would help; I'm editing that in now.

Comment: I agree it is not a true duplicate, though closely related.  My answer to the other question does cover "Reading from more than one file at a time".

Comment: Fair enough -- but there's much less digging to get to that answer here than there, so it's clearer to a reader *why* it's a good duplicate (and hence, likely to get less pushback).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it without `paste`, but you can avoid `cut` assigning all variables in one `read`:

```
while read -r X Y CHAR; do
    echo "X = $X; Y = $Y; CHAR = $CHAR";
done < "$file"
```

Comment: paste is not a problem, the cuts were :)

Answer (score 7):

You can call `read` thrice, each from a different file descriptor.

```
# Use && to stop reading once the shortest file is consumed
while read -u 3 -r X &&
      read -u 4 -r Y &&
      read -u 5 -r CHAR; do
    ...
done 3< X.txt 4< Y.txt 5< CHAR.txt
```

(`-u` is a `bash` extension, used for clarity. For POSIX compatibility, each call would look something like `read -r X <&3`.)